# Mapping Dictionary Values to Pandas Data-frame Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this dictionary:

```
 j =  {1: {'help': 2},
 2: {'chocolate': 1, 'help': 1},
 3: {'chocolate': 1, 'help': 1}}
```

and this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'docId': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ],
                       'sent': ['help', 'chocolate', 'chocolate', 'help', 'help', 'help']})
```

and I want to match the values according to docId and term so it should look like this:

```
docId  sent        freq
1      help         2
2      chocolate    1
3      chocolate    1
1      help         2
2      help         1
3      help         1
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this, I was working on using map and apply but I didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Remake your dictionary

With tuples as keys, you can `map` the `get` method over zipped columns

```
J = {(x, y): v for x, V in j.items() for y, v in V.items()}

df.assign(freq=[*map(J.get, zip(df.docId, df.sent))])


   docId       sent  freq
0      1       help     2
1      2  chocolate     1
2      3  chocolate     1
3      1       help     2
4      2       help     1
5      3       help     1
```

---

### Or don't

You can use a `lambda` in `map` that takes two arguments and pass the iterables that supply the arguments.

```
df.assign(freq=[*map(lambda x, y: j[x][y], df.docId, df.sent)])

   docId       sent  freq
0      1       help     2
1      2  chocolate     1
2      3  chocolate     1
3      1       help     2
4      2       help     1
5      3       help     1
```

Answer (score 6):

How about a list comprehension? You can chain two `dict.get` calls (one for each level of nesting).

```
df['freq'] = [
    j.get(x, {}).get(y, np.nan) for x, y in df[['docId', 'sent']].values]
df

   docId       sent  freq
0      1       help     2
1      2  chocolate     1
2      3  chocolate     1
3      1       help     2
4      2       help     1
5      3       help     1
```

---

If you can guarantee all entries exist in `j`, you can simplify the above to,

```
df['freq'] = [j[x][y] for x, y in df[['docId', 'sent']].values]
df

   docId       sent  freq
0      1       help     2
1      2  chocolate     1
2      3  chocolate     1
3      1       help     2
4      2       help     1
5      3       help     1
```

Comment: Chaining dict.get worked for my when I had another level in my nested dictionary. I had trouble adapting some of the other answers, in case anyone is trying a more complicated dictionary

Answer (score 4):

IIUC try something different using `reindex`

```
s=pd.DataFrame(j).stack().reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.sent,df.docId])).reset_index()
s
Out[81]: 
        sent  docId    0
0       help      1  2.0
1  chocolate      2  1.0
2  chocolate      3  1.0
3       help      1  2.0
4       help      2  1.0
5       help      3  1.0
```

---

End Up using this method `lookup`

```
df['Freq']=pd.DataFrame(j).lookup(df.sent,df.docId)
df
Out[95]: 
   docId       sent  Freq
0      1       help   2.0
1      2  chocolate   1.0
2      3  chocolate   1.0
3      1       help   2.0
4      2       help   1.0
5      3       help   1.0
```

Comment: You beat me to this solution. +1 :)

Comment: @ScottBoston maybe you can try `merge` :-) would like to see that function as well : -)

Comment: I was trying merge, but has some dtype problems.

Comment: @ScottBoston `s=pd.DataFrame(j).reset_index().melt('index')
;df['Freq']=df.merge(s.assign(variable=s.variable.astype(int)),left_on=['sent','docId'],right_on=['index','variable'],how='left')['value']
`

Comment: `df.join(pd.DataFrame(j).unstack().rename_axis([*df]).rename('freq'), on=[*df])`

Comment: @piRSquared yes that is nice , I end up using lookup :-)

Comment: OOHH!  `lookup` I like it!

Comment: `lookup` is nice, should have submitted that as a different answer, I'd upvote that one too.